What are the x intercepts (wherever defined) for $ \vert x^2 -8x +15 \vert ^ {(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-5) \over (x-2)} = 1 $
The original question asked was the following :
(Source : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U7khRKh12GlaSY73210oQd2170JiXEGY/view)
Rita took some of her friends for picnic. Her friends are at x−intercepts of the equation
$ \vert x^2 -8x +15 \vert ^ {(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-5) \over (x-2)} =1 $
wherever defined. Considering there are only one
friend at each location (i.e., at x−intercept). How many friends she took for picnic?
The solution mentioned for above problem is 4,
but I get it as 1,as follows:
According to law of indices, $ a^0 = 1 $ where $ a \ne 0 $ and $a \in \mathbb{R} $ .
So, according to $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-5) \over (x-2)$ $  = 0$
permitted values for x are 1,3 and 5
It cannot be 2 due to presence of 2 in denominator. ...(1)
Solving , $ \vert x^2 -8x +15 \vert $ yields 3 and 5 as x intercept .
The value of this equation will be 0 if we substitute 3 and 5 in it, therefore these values need to be omitted (law of indices $ a^0 =1 $ where $ a \ne 0 $ and $a \in \mathbb{R} $ .....(2)
Therefore, only allowable intercept (considering (1) and (2)) should be 1.
Am I solving it the right way ?

This is right, but note this:
For $a=1$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ follow $a^x = 1$.
So consider $|x^2-8x+15| = 1$, implies:
$$x^2-8x+14=0 \\ x^2-8x+16=0$$
which is hold by $x=4$, $x=4-\sqrt{2}$, and $x=4+\sqrt{2}$, all this is allowed for our equation. Hence we have $4 "x-intercepts"$:
$$x\in\{1,4,4-\sqrt{2},4+\sqrt{2}\}$$

Thank you for pointing out the omitted possibility.

Can i ask u. This source is for your uni, school, or course?

One of previous year's question of entrance examination for IIT Madras Diploma program.
